# Retain the virtual address range after freeing shared memory segment

Tags: linux, memory, shared-memory, mmap

In my application, for some reason, I want to overwrite the shared memory mapping with a file mapping.

To elaborate, the application first allocates shared memory using shmget() and shmat() to get 'void* addr'. At a later point I want to overwrite the address range starting at 'addr' by a file mapping.
If I do shmdt() the virtual address is released and a mmap() might not give me the same address.

Is there a way be keep the address range but release the shared memory segment.

Appreciate your answers!

Comment: You can (in practice) simply keep a copy of the pointer after the `shmdt()` (though technically this is probably undefined behavior) and use the `addr` argument to `mmap()` to have the mapping be put in the same place, though the OS might not honor this request. You might thus want `MAP_FIXED`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Forgot to add that there are other threads in the program who might be doing mmap's. If other thread in the mean time does overlapping mmap, MAP_FIXED might fail or overwrite the other valid mapping.

Comment: As I understand, `mmap()` is going to take a lock internally, so concurrent `mmap()`s will not provide a performance benefit. Consequently, you don't lose anything by synchronizing your memory-mapping operations to avoid this scenario.

Comment: sigh! wish I could change the design of the code. I am contributing a patch to an open source project and have to make minimalist changes. Btw, the concurrent mmap() is not for performance, its just the artifact of application design.

Comment: In this case, I don't see any way to ensure correct operation. I will add that the requirement of the new mapping being in the place of the previous shared memory is *extremely* suspect anyway.

Comment: It uses SHM with SHM_HUGETLB to allocate large page memory, not for IPC. Nothing shady! :-)